# Parent display: flex not applying to child divs?

Tags: html, css

The R, P, and S end up being stacked on top of each other in a column rather than being side by side.

I've been going through freeCodeCamp and theOdinProject and this issue has come up a few times for me, I usually ended up just assigning each div an ID and using CSS to target it with a 'display: flex.'

I figured I should finally find out why this isn't working so if someone could please explain it to me, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Here's my HTML:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.keys {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet.css' type=text/css href='stylesheet.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='keys'>
        <div data-key='82' class='key'>
            <kbd>R</kbd>
        </div>
        <div data-key='80' class='key'>
            <kbd>P</kbd>
        </div>
        <div data-key='83' class='key'>
            <kbd>S</kbd>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: typo `rel='stylesheet.css'` --> `rel='stylesheet'`

Comment: The code works for me, so I guess the typo is the reason why it's not working. Always try to put some CSS in the actual document before linking to it.

Comment: I see them in row ?

Comment: Ah thank you guys, what a silly mistake! I appreciated the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "flex: 1".

```
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
```

^ should do it.

If you want to space the items, try `justify-content: space-evenly`